# Converting images to PPM P3 (using convert command)

Tags: command-line, 10.10, image-processing, convert, imagemagick

I was wondering if there is a quick way to convert a given image to a PPM image that is in version P3. The `convert` command returns it in P6 by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`convert foo.ppm -compress none bar.ppm` found here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#pbmplus